# How to connect a Twilio number to a Twilio flow

Tags: python, twilio

I am working on a project to connect a phone number to a Twilio flow project. I've created a flow and I've added a number the flow does not work.

[image]

[image]

I contacted support about this.

This is not okay. I followed the specific instructions in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=180&v=VRxirse1UfQ&embeds_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twilio.com%2F&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjYsMjM4NTE&feature=emb_title

and nothing works as expected.

Expected:

```
Send hi and receive: 

1. What are the positive results or outcomes you have achieved lately?

2. What are the strengths and resources you have available to you to get even more results and were likely the reason you got the results in the first question.

3. What are your current priorities?

4. What do you and your team need to be focused on right now?

5. What are the benefits to all involved-you, your team and all other stakeholders who will be impacted by achieving your priority focus.

6. How can we (you and/or your team) move close? 

7. What action steps are needed?

8. What are you going to do today?

9. What are you doing tomorrow ?

10. What did you do yesterday?

Please respond in the order that the questions appear.
```

Actual:

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - Thanks for the message. Configure your number's SMS URL to change this message.Reply HELP for help.Reply STOP to unsubscribe.Msg&Data rates may apply.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may already know Twilio is not recognizing the Studio Flow you've created as the default action to perform for the phone number's Messaging function.

It looks like the select menu under "(When) A Message Comes In" is set to the default SMS Webhook, which is the demo URL provided by Twilio.

**You have instead set your Studio Flow under "Primary Handler Fails" which is essentially just a back-up event in the event the Primary Handler (that is set to the default Webhook) is unable to be accessed.**

What you need to do is change "(When) A Message Comes In" from `Webhook` to `Studio Flow` using the drop-down menu and then a list of your Studio Flows containing "Commitment Process" will appear and be able to be selected.